# How can I remove an element in Ox?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, rubygems, nokogiri

How can I remove an element when parsing XML with Ox?

Ox has an append method `- (Object) <<(node)` but doesn't seem to have a `- (Element) remove` method. Nokogiri has a `remove` function, does Ox have an equivalent?

http://www.ohler.com/ox/Ox/Element.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this document:

```
doc = Ox::Document.new(:version => '1.0')
top = Ox::Element.new('top')
top[:name] = 'sample'
doc << top
```

Now you can observe:

```
doc.nodes.class => Array
```

Your nodes are just a regular ruby array. 
And thus you have all the Enumerable functionality combined with the Array facilities of Ruby.

To delete the element we've created above, you can do this:

```
doc.nodes.delete top
```

Or an index-based removal if that's what you need:

```
doc.nodes.delete_at 0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess my question is really once you delete the nodes, how can you replace the existing element? The `delete` method isn't `delete!`. Does that make sense? There don't seem to be any methods for replacing elements... or deleting them.

Comment: You have an array of objects. You can delete them and replace them as much as you want. `delete!` is not an Array method. You can use `collect!` or `map!` to replace elements in-place. Please refer to the Array documentation.

Comment: Ah, ok I think I know what was up, I was trying to delete from an xpath expression: `doc.root.locate("Story/Paragraph/*").clear` when I should have been deleting like this `doc.root.locate("Story/Paragraph")[0].nodes.clear`. Doesn't seem like it should make much of a difference...